# I keep getting a node gyp exit 2 error, how do I resolve?

Tags: node-gyp

I have an error with node-gyp on my Mac 13 m1.

This is the error:

```
    1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/nickmorgan/WebstormProjects/MX Digital - Corporate Website/Frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/16.11.1/bin/node" "/Users/nickmorgan/WebstormProjects/MX Digital - Corporate Website/Frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/nickmorgan/WebstormProjects/MX Digital - Corporate Website/Frontend/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v16.11.1
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix? it's really annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error because my `node-sass` version is `^5`.

Updating `node-sass` to `^6` helps.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

[image]